# How to make a staying on top menu without losing parts of the menu

Tags: html, css, menu, navigation, fixed

I'm developing my web design recently, I tried to use as much css as I can without javascript. Problem came when I'm making my navigation menu which should stay on top. Here is a copy of my code :

```css
ul {
 background: rgba(37,39,44,.80);
 list-style-type:none;
 margin : 0;
 padding: 0;
 overflow:visible;
 font-family:Kreon;
 min-width:1349px;
 width:100%;
 top:0;
 position:fixed;
 border-bottom: 5px solid #22A85B;
 
}
li {
 float : right;
}

li a{
 display:block;
 color : white;
 text-align:center;
 padding: 15px 20px 15px 20px;
 text-decoration :none;
 border-right:0.5px solid #22a85b;
 transition: 0.3s all;
}
li a:hover {
 background:#22a85b;
}
.dropdown-arrow {
 position:relative;
 top:1px;
 display:inline-block;
 width:0;
 height:0;
 margin-left:5px;
 border: 4px solid transparent;
 border-top-color:#fff;
}
.dropdown {
 float:right;
 position:relative;
 display:inline-block;
 color: white;
 text-align:center;
 padding: 15px 20px 15px 20px;
 cursor:pointer;
 border-right:1px solid #22A85B;
}
.dropdown:hover{
 background:#22a85b;
}
.dropdown:focus {
 pointer-events:none;
 background:#eee;
 color:#000;
}
.dropdown-content {
 position:absolute;
 background-color:#eee;
 min-width:150px;
 z-index:1;
 opacity:0;
 visibility:hidden;
 transition: 0.2s linear;
 margin-top:36px;
 margin-left:-50px;
 border : 1px solid #bbb;
 border-top:none;
}
.dropdown-content a{
 text-align:right;
 color: black;
 font-family:kreon;
 text-decoration:none;
 padding: 10px 15px 10px 15px;
 display:block;
 transition: 0.1s linear;
 border-bottom: 1px solid #20D23F;
}
.dropdown-content a:hover{
 background: #22a85b;
 color:#fff;
}
.dropdown:focus .dropdown-content{
 opacity:1;
 visibility:visible;
 pointer-events:auto;
}
.dropdown:focus .dropdown-arrow{
 border: 4px solid transparent;
 border-bottom-color:#000;
 margin-bottom : 4px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
<li style ="float:left; margin-left:150px; border-left:1px solid #22A85B;"><a href="#">Logo Here</a></li>
<li style="margin-right:60px;"><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Hire Us!</a></li>
<div tabindex="0" class="dropdown">
<li class="fol">Follow Us <span class="dropdown-arrow"></span></li>
 <div class="dropdown-content">
 <a href="http://twitter.com">Twitter</a>
 <a href="http://fb.com">Facebook</a>
 <a href="http://pinterest.com" style="border-bottom:none; border-bottom-radius:0.3cm;">Pinterest</a>
 </div>
</div>
<li><a href="#">Be Our Designer!</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
<li style="border-left:1px solid #22A85B;"><a href="#">How Do We Work</a></li>
</ul>
```

So to make the menu stay on top, I put `position : fixed;` on my CSS. But when I resize the browser, the floating menu move to the bottom of some menu. Then I tried to set the `min-width` only to find out that some of my menu were missing when I resize my browser (can't see it even though I'm scrolling to the left) due the `position : fixed`.

Any help from you guys would be appreciated. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

<strike>I cannot reproduce the described problem when resizing my browser.</strike>

**Edit:** I think I do now understand what you mean (the line break in the menu when you reduce the screen width). You can't change that, only if you change the menu on smaller screen sizes bar like Bootstrap does (see the example below)

See https://jsfiddle.net/bdtbz74f/ (Fiddle of your code)

I also added

```
body {
  margin-top: 60px;
}
ul {
  width:100%;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  position:fixed;   
}
```

and remove the `min-width`. The `margin-top` on the `body` prevents the content from hiding behind your navbar.

**Tip: Take a look at the CSS code of Bootstraps [Fixed Top Navbar Example](https://getbootstrap.com/examples/navbar-fixed-top/)**